# How to copy old table including generated column to new table in mariadb?

Tags: java, mariadb

I tried
    CREATE TABLE table2 LIKE table1; 
Then
    INSERT INTO table2 SELECT * FROM table1;

My question is in two parts :

1. All the fields are copied (included generated) but generated column is not auto populated once i fill base column in new table.
2. ID field in  the new  table which was auto incremented in the old table is also not behaving as expected. Its value is not auto incremented.

Comment: Sounds worth a bug report.

Comment: Please paste the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE table1` and an example of the contents which does not meet your expectations.